# The use of slash in python string and regex

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

example:

```
s = r't\s t t\\s'
print(re.findall('\s',s))
print(re.findall('\\s',s))
```

I found that the two statements print the same result: `[' ', ' ']`，which indicates that `\s`and`\\s`is same in Python's string class. Actually, when I type the following code in Python's interaction interface, I got this:

```
>>> str1 = '\s'
>>> str1
'\\s'
```

So it seems that python would convert `\s`to `\\s`. Why would Python do this and what is this for? Is it the same in other languages like Java?

**Actually, what I'm asking is that: In Python, if I want to match whitespace, the regex and the String I input could both be `"\s"`, right? However, in Java, the regex should be `"\s"`, while the String should be `"\\s"`. The two languages seem to treat String "\s" differently. Why?**

Comment: *Is it the same in other languages like Java?* -- Yes, backslashes are escaped.

Comment: http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Thx! So If I want to match spaces in Java, the String `"\s" `or `"\\s"` both work?

Comment: `"\s"` is a single whitespace. `"\\s"` is a backslash followed by the character **s**

Comment: @cricket_007, Thx! But actually, what I'm asking is that: In Python, if I want to match whitespace, the regex and the string I input could both be `"\s"`. However, in Java, the regex should be `"\s"`, while the String should be `"\\s"`, so why this is different in these two languages?

Answer (score 1):

Python is just escaping it, so when it sees an "\" continued by a letter and if that letter doesn't have any special meaning then Python actually escapes the backslash, instead of throwing any errors.

Python interactive interface uses `repr` to return a string containing a printable representation of an object. So that function is adding the extra backslash to indicate that it's a literal backslash.

If you use print function to show the value of `str1`, you will get it printed in the stdout with just 1 backslash.

Look at this example:

```
str1 = '\s'

print str1
print str1.__repr__()
```

Comment: Thx. Actually, what I'm asking is that: In Python, if I want to match whitespace, the regex and the string I input could both be `"\s"`, right? However, in Java, the regex should be `"\s"`, while the String should be `"\\s"`. The two languages seem to treat String `"\s"` differently.

Answer (score 1):

> So it seems that python would convert \sto \s.

Don't confuse string representations with the actual content of the string. String representation is the way you write a string in source code, which may not exactly be the same as the string actually in memory. Backslashes are parsed specially to allow you to write non-printable characters using the backslash syntax. In this case, \s is not a valid escape sequence so the python parser interprets it literally as backslash-s. In memory, the string is still a character sequence containing the letters: `\, s

str class have a `__repr__()`/`repr()` method that returns a string that contains the source-code representation of the string, this is the string that gets printed when you don't use `print` statement in the REPL. This allows you to copy paste those string and reuse it in another part of the shell, but it isn't really what is stored in memory and how python interprets the string. When printing **repr**, python always escapes a literal backslash, this is to remove ambiguity on whether the backslash is interpreted as escape sequence or as a literal character.

> Why would Python do this and what is this for? Is it the same in other languages like Java?

Most languages' string literal do interpret backslash escape sequence, although different languages treats invalid escape sequence differently. In Python, invalid backslash escape sequence is silently treated as literal backslash instead of producing an error. You'd probably encounter this kind of issue more often in Python because it has an ubiquitous `repr()` protocol and the default use of `repr` in the REPL shell.

Comment: Thx! This is my understanding of the second question: When encountering an invalid backslash escape sequence, Python would silently treat it as a literal backslash(like adding a backslash before it), but languages like Java would producing an error. Is it correct?